# Title / head above plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I made a time plot in R, but now I want to set a title "Phase 4" above the plot. I already tried with "head="Phase 4" and "title = Phase 4" but this didn't work

```
 library("extrafont")
 plot <- ts.plot(newdata, col=1:5)
 print(plot)
 dev.copy2pdf(file="C:/Users/X/Desktop/timeplot_fase4.pdf",height=3, 
 width=4,title="Phase 4", family="CM Roman",pointsize=12);
 dev.off ();
```

Someone who knows how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the title in your plot statement.

```
plot <- ts.plot(newdata, col=1:5, main="Phase 4")
```